# Not able to use Custom Directive in a component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, frontend, angular6

I have created a custom directive with name `InfiniteScroll`  and its selector name is `appInfiniteScroll`.
[`infinitescroll.directive.ts`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugS4Q.png).
I have imported in a module name `infinitescroll.module.ts`  [infinitescroll.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42VF0.png).Then I imporetd this module in `app.component.ts`.[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rshm8.png).
Still when I try to use it in my component `user-list.component.ts` like this `<div appInfiniteScroll></div>`,It dont work.
[user-list.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39H8l.png)(**see this first line of this html**).Please tell me a way or at least what am I doing wrong.Thanks.

Comment: Please post the actual code as text rather than an image. What error are you getting?

Comment: check spelling appInfiniteScroll. it should be appInfinitescroll.

Comment: @user184994 there's no error in the code,. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: like @KesavanR is saying, the spelling is incorrect

Comment: When you use custom directives and make some typo, Angular will not complain because there could be some native attributes or some custom attributes (which are not defined within angular) and used for styling purposes. So, they are right. You made a typo